# I get mime type error when attempting to load css fonts

Tags: html, css, mime-types, mime

I loaded a font and i get mime type error when i save the file :

And i dont understand what exactly going on.

this is the html code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" src="Branda-yolq.ttf">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 id="welcomingText">Welcome to QUIZ</h1>
    <button id="init-button">Start Quiz!</button>
    <div class="contentDivDisplayed">
        <p id='question'>question</p>
        <span><input type="radio" autocomplete="off" name="hh"><p></p></span>
        <span><input type="radio" autocomplete="off" name="hh"><p></p></span>
        <span><input type="radio" autocomplete="off" name="hh"><p></p></span>
        <span><input type="radio" autocomplete="off" name="hh"><p></p></span>
        <p id="quest-num">questionNum</p>
        <button id="next-button">Next</button>
    </div>
    <div id="alert-box"></div>
    <script src="quiz.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

and this is the css code:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "skot";
    src: url("Branda-yolq.ttf");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This line is causing the problem:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" src="Branda-yolq.ttf">
```

You are telling the browser to load a stylesheet, but instead you give it a font-file. That's how you got the MIME Type error. Remove the line and the error should go. You are already loading the font in the css.